# createStripeCharge gcloud Javascript function error not defined issue

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am leveraging these JavaScript [Stripe GCloud functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js) in order to create new customers and process charges in my iOS app.

As per the comments in the function I am creating a child `charge` node under the `charges` branch in order to trigger the `createStripeCharge` gcloud function and process the charge as per below.

[image]

But I am getting the following error in the logs console

> ReferenceError: error is not defined

```
exports.createStripeCharge = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const val = snap.val();
      // Look up the Stripe customer id written in createStripeCustomer
      return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${context.params.userId}/customer_id`)
          .once('value').then((snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.val();
          }).then((customer) => {
            // Create a charge using the pushId as the idempotency key
            // protecting against double charges
            const amount = val.amount;
            const idempotencyKey = context.params.id;
            const charge = {amount, currency, customer};
            if (val.source !== null) {
              charge.source = val.source;
            }
            return stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key: idempotencyKey});
          }).then((response) => {
            // If the result is successful, write it back to the database
            return snap.ref.set(response);
          }).catch((error) => {
            // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-friendly way, while
            // still logging an exception with StackDriver
            return snap.ref.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error));
          }).then(() => {
            return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
          });
        });
```

Comment: Are you missing a `currency` variable? Line 13 refers to `currency` but I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: I don't believe that is the issue. I re-deployed my function with commenting-out the lines starting from `.catch((error) => {...` and the payment was processed successfully. The funny thing is that this same function as-is has been used in the gcloud function error reporting official documentation as an example on this link [Report errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors)

Comment: Found the issue and fixed it! - as it turns out the line `.then(() => {...` is missing `error` and so it should be `.then((error) => {...` so that it can be referenced in the line that follows it just below it.